# exiting C# function execution if one of the variable value during execution becomes true

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a function Parent() and a boolean Class Property Watch with default value true.
This fn Parent() is calling several Child functions.
Lets assume during execution of this function or any of  the child functions Watch Changes its value to false , i want the execution to stop and exit the Parent function.
Parent is returning void.

This is a single threaded execution , no async and Task constructs being used

Comment: Is the watch property set only by the child functions or can externally something set it from a different thread? You didn't mention mutlithreading/tasks so I assume the children get called sequentially.  If it is only set by the children have the child exit when it sets the variable to false and check after each child is executed in the parent function if it is false and return if that is the case.

Comment: How does your "Watch" property changes?  is it an affectation done by the child's method ?

Comment: its only set by child functions , check in parent functions how do you mean using if on every child function call ?

Comment: I think this is a case where throwing an exception may be the acceptable method here. The child methods can throw the exception, and the parent can catch it and exit. This doesn't require that many changes to the structure, and you wouldn't even need the "watch" property.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer looks like that's one of the ways without polluting my code with too many if constructs

Comment: BTW any person down-voting should explain the reasoning . It does not helps if the reason is unclear

Comment: Exceptions as a measure for control flow is usually considered a code smell and bad design outweighing what you consider polluted code.

Comment: @FrankJ without knowing the context here you can't categorically say that its code smell, what it sounds like though is that something "exceptional" occurs that requires the rest of the processing stream to stop, which is a valid use for exceptions.

Comment: True but without further knowledge of the scenario the rule of thumb stands and hence the word "usually" in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is to use exceptions for this:

```
public class TestClass
{

    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            ChildMethod1();
            ChildMethod2();
        }
        catch (InvalidStateException ise)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void ChildMethod1()
    {
        //do stuff, and then if the "watch" is set to true:
        throw new InvalidStateException();
    }

    public void ChildMethod2()
    {
        //do stuff, and then if the "watch" is set to true:
        throw new InvalidStateException();
    }
}

public class InvalidStateException : Exception { }
```

Here I've defined a new exception `InvalidStateException` that the `ChildMethodX` can raise when it wants the parent method to stop execution. In the parent method you try/catch all the child calls, and when one throws, it stops the execution and skips into the catch.

**Note:** Exceptions occur because something exceptional happens. If you expect that this would be a normal flow of logic, then I would implore you to try something that avoids exceptions. Exceptions are expensive performance wise. For example, without using exceptions you could do something like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool Watch { get; set; }

    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        Func<bool> c1Call = () => { Child1Method(); return Watch; };
        Func<bool> c2Call = () => { ChildMethod2(); return Watch; };

        if (c1Call())
            return;

        if (c2Call())
            return;
    }

    public void Child1Method()
    {
        //Do something, then this happens:
        Watch = true;
    }

    public void ChildMethod2()
    {
        //Do something, then maybe this happens:
        Watch = true;
    }
}
```

Where you could modify the `Func<>` delegates to take any number of arguments. There are a dozen ways to skin this cat, but almost all of them involve checking the flag after calling the function to determine if you want to exit or not. If you functions return `void`, consider changing them to return bool so you could do something like:

```
if (ChildMethod1()) return;
```

Which is pretty concise. Otherwise you can use strange combinations of lambda's and delegates, but when you get down to it you have to ask yourself, is avoiding typing a couple extra "if" statements worth the loss in code maintainability?

Comment: This is usually considered a bad practice [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd264997.aspx)  as it might even get flagged by profilers.

Comment: I think the key word in that article is "high number", who knows, this could only happen once per application run. Its impossible to know without quite a bit more context on the OP's part. From what he was describing, it may be a perfectly valid use of exceptions.

Comment: it would happen only once during my code execution, plan is to stop execution as soon the Watch value change occurs , not to call any more child functions

Comment: @RonBeyer please consider updating your post with your comment - good solution for once-in-a-while exceptional condition (like validation of service call arguments), but not accepted for flow control which OP's post seem to imply.

Comment: @Ron excellent answer with the alternatives +1. I was mostly worried to give bad advise regarding best practices to somebody who seems to be at a beginner level.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo mock up how you can construct that.
It demonstrates a workflow where Child2 sets the variable to false and exits after that and therefore never executed Child3.

However I would suggest to have the child functions return a bool instead. Seems not a good design what you are suggesting for a single threaded application.

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Watch { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        this.Watch = true;
    }

    public void Parent()
    {
        this.Child1();
        if(this.Watch == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Child2();
        if(this.Watch == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Child3();
        if(this.Watch == false)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Child1()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    public void Child2()
    {
        this.Watch = false;
    }

    public void Child3()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way that parent gets informed of Watch value change without the if Statements , your assumptions are right i will edit my post

Comment: Well the information piece in this is the `Watch` variable that informs the parent. To test if a condition is true or false  you have to - per definition - test the condition.

Comment: @paranjai to check for condition one need to use `if` (or similar construct like `while(cond)` ). I'm not sure what you expect with "gets informed".

Answer (score 0):

You can either execute each Child function in a different thread and have a loop in the Parent function monitor the Watch value or you can check the Watch value after each Child call.  Without a code example or more information, it is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn Parent()
{
    childfn();
    if( !Watch )
        return;

}
```

Though might be better to have child functions return bool and check that rather than use class property.

Comment: that can be done , i was wondering if there was a way i dont have to write if statement for every child function

Answer (score 0):

i assume this is yr code structure.. if my assumption is wrong please correct me

I also have a question - all the child functions have same signature ? if so I'll suggest approach based on delegates. Otherwise here is a simple example

```
bool Watch { get; set; }


    // Parent is control center, calling one child after another
    void Parent()
    {
        ChildOne(1);
        if (Watch == false)
            return;

        ChildTwo(1,3);
        if (Watch == false)
            return;
    }

   /// signature type 1
    void ChildOne(int a)
    {

    }

    /// signature type 2
    void ChildTwo(int a, int b)
    {
        Watch = false;
    }
```

EDIT 1 
here is the approach if all functions have same signature

```
  class ChildFuntionExecutor
    {
        public Func<int,int> ChildFuntion;
        public int Operand1;
        public void Evaluate()
        {
             ChildFuntion(Operand1);
        }
    }

    bool Watch { get; set; }


    // Parent is control center, calling one child after another
    void Parent()
    {
        // register all child functions 
        List<ChildFuntionExecutor> childFuntionQueue = new List<ChildFuntionExecutor>();
        childFuntionQueue.Add(new ChildFuntionExecutor { Operand1 = 10, ChildFuntion = this.ChildOne });
        childFuntionQueue.Add(new ChildFuntionExecutor { Operand1 = 10, ChildFuntion = this.ChildOne });


        foreach (var item in childFuntionQueue)
        {
            item.Evaluate();
            if (Watch == false)
                return;
        }
    }

    /// signature type 1
    int ChildOne(int a)
    {
        return a * 10;
    }

    /// signature type 1
    int ChildTwo(int a)
    {
        Watch = false;
        return a * 10;
    }
```

Comment: No child Functions have different signature

Comment: Alright .. I'll change my code, to give an approach based on delegates

Comment: Why the wrapper? Why not just a `List<Func<int, int>>`? Then it would be `childFuntionQueue.Add((o) => ChildOne(o))`, and then you wouldn't be throwing away the return value. The for loop then turns into `int retVal = item(operand);` or whatever it needs to be.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I'm usually an advocate of wrappers, since it gives a clear context. But in this case, I second your approach - much more readable